# How do I create a loop in java that checks a single scanner line for next()

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("Enter some stuff:");
    while (input.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(input.next()+ " ");
    }
```

Whenever this runs, it asks the user for input, then prints it all out. However, what I want, is a loop that will print out all of the tokens of a scanner. Then, it realizes there are no more tokens, and the loop exits.

Comment: It's not clear, please provide an example. Also, don't give us a code without declaring and initializing all the objects that are used (namely `input`).

Comment: Explain the difference between "prints it all out", and "when there are no more tokens, the loop exits".

Comment: Sorry to be a prude, but we do try to avoid [vulgar language](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) here...

Answer (score 2):

Well, you'd want to read the tokens into an `ArrayList`, like this:

```
List<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
// read them all in and add them to our list
while (input.hasNext())
    store.add(input.next());
// now print them all out
for (String s: store)
    System.out.print(s+ " ");
```

What this does is to read them all in, and put them into the `ArrayList`; then, the reading loop exits when there's nothing more to read. After that, it prints them all out. I think this is what you have in mind. If you wanted to print them while you were adding them, then you could

```
List<String> store = new ArrayList<String>();
// read them all in and add them to our list
while (input.hasNext()) {
    String s = input.next();
    store.add(s);
    System.out.print(s+ " ");
}
for (String s: store) {
    // do whatever you like with them
}
```

Comment: +1 I was literally about to post this same exact answer. The pains of slow typing @chiastic-security

Comment: @Tetramputechture It's what has made me more or less give up on writing SO answers on a tablet! So slow it's often redundant by the time I've finished...

Comment: But what if, the values I want to store are of different data types? Suppose I want to be able to differentiate between integers and certain keywords that may be input. And reject all others

Comment: @WalkerGain You would want to detect these as you read them in, and process them accordingly. In the `while` loop, you can use `input.hasNextInt()` etc., and then `input.nextInt()` to get the integer and store it where you like. You can even use `.hasNext(String pattern)` with a regular expression to determine whether it's a particular sort of word coming next. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just copy, try to understand mate:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class PrintStuff {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter some shit seperated by space:");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str=""; 
    try {
        str = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("IO error trying to read bitch!");
    }

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }
}

}
```